# Login button disabled initially but both the user name and password model having cached value in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, caching

We have log-in page which ask username and  password to proceed further. After giving valid details, it will navigate to desired page, that time chrome browser allowing the popup to save the password for next time. We saved both the user name and password.

```
<form  class="loginform" name="loginForm">
 <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="username"   required />
<input type="password" id="password-field" name="password" ng-model="password" required />

 <input type="submit" ng-click="submitted=true" ng-disabled="loginForm.username.$invalid ||(loginForm.password.$invalid)" value="LOG IN"  />
</form>
```

After caching the username and password, from next time both text boxes having the values but still login button was disabled.

because "password" model coming as undefined, even though password textbox contains some value.because of this login button gets disabled.

when i click some where in form / textbox the button gets enabled.(i.e. that time password model contains the value). I am not sure why initially password model coming as empty, after user interaction with form it is giving the value.
is that behavior of cached password in chrome browser ?

Comment: try this expression {{loginForm.$invalid}} into your HTML file and see is it true. If true then try {{loginForm.$error}} and see error and is there any error.

Comment: @surjeet loginForm.invalid = true. loginForm.$error password invalid true, when i click some where in form it is changing to false.

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this.

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="submitted=true" ng-disabled="(loginForm.username.$invalid || !username) ||(loginForm.password.$invalid || !password)" value="LOG IN"  />
```

or you can calculate length. `username.length == 0 || password.length == 0`

Comment: my code (save button disabled condition is working fine). The concern is even though the password text box contains some value , password model coming as undefined. because of this button gets disabled. when i click on that textbox value gets updated in the model. and button gets enabled.

Comment: The question is password textbox contains some value(i.e. cached pssword in browser). But still password model coming as undefined.